# Creating a Byte array from an Image

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

What is the best way to create a byte array from an Image? I have seen many methods but in WinRT none of them worked.

Comment: was this [Charles Petzold article] (http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/08/WriteableBitmap-Pixel-Arrays-in-CSharp-and-CPlusPlus.html) one that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static class ByteArrayConverter
    {
        public static async Task<byte[]> ToByteArrayAsync(StorageFile file)
        {
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
                {
                    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                    byte[] Bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
                    reader.ReadBytes(Bytes);
                    return Bytes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

here is one way
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

alternatively if you have the Image saved on FS, just create a StorageFile and use the stream to get byte[]

Answer (score 1):

The magic is in the [DataReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx).  For example ...

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png"));
var buf = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
var bytes = new byte[buf.Length];
var dr = DataReader.FromBuffer(buf);
dr.ReadBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: i guess he meant reading the pixel data, not the file contents

Comment: thought the same thing... BUT in order to get the pixel data you have to reload the Image (capital "I") into a WriteableBitmap, and if you're doing that why not just read the source directly as @JP mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the method [from Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/08/WriteableBitmap-Pixel-Arrays-in-CSharp-and-CPlusPlus.html):

```
        byte[] srcPixels;
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg");
        RandomAccessStreamReference streamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri);

        using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType fileStream = await streamRef.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
            BitmapFrame frame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0);

            PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await frame.GetPixelDataAsync();
            srcPixels = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();

        }
```