# Get text from PDF stored in LocalFolder using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, itext, pdftotext

I am trying to get the text from a PDF stored in localStorage in a Windows Phone 8.1 application,but I always get an FileNotFoundException.

To explain the whole story, I get a PDF from an online source, I store it to a folder with name same as the username (The username is an email address, but I tried also without the @ sign) of the user and then I want to get some text from the PDF file. I use iTextSharp and follow the examples, but cannot succeed. When I send the PDF to the Launcher is opening succesfully with another app like Acrobat Reader.

My function is like below. I first send an **PDF Object**, which has an attribute called **Path** and it is stored to folder specific to the username of the user.
Then I get the pdf as a **StorageFile** Item. When I  create the **PDFReader** calling the constructor I get a FileNotFoundException. Does anybody knows or can guess what can be the problem? Is iTextSharp compatible with Windows Phone 8.1?

```
internal async Task<bool> OpenPdfFromDownloadedCollections(PDF pdfToOpen, string username)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var pdfFolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(username + "PDFs");

            var pdf = await pdfFolder.GetFileAsync(Object.Path);

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf.Path))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    string thePage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its);
                    string[] theLines = thePage.Split('\n');
                    foreach (var theLine in theLines)
                    {
                        text.AppendLine(theLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what version of itextsharp are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.5.6.0 from nuget library

Comment: As I can understand from other Posts and videos it may not work with Windows Phone version because of some conflicts with System.Drawing.dll.

Comment: Same as i heard. I think you need to check if for other components that can do the trick for you. There is a blogpost of Microsoft http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/04/15/reading-pdf-and-xps-on-your-windows-8-application-using-winrt.aspx maybe thats what you are looking for.

Comment: The others are all paid and expensive, but are working as I tried a trial one. What I need is to get a barcode from a pdf and display it on screen. Do you know any free library to convert pdf to Image or Text except this one?

Comment: do you want to extract the barcode picture or just show a pdf site on screen?

Comment: Can you convert the `StorageFile` to a byte array and pass that to `PdfReader()`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15358695/231316

Comment: I did and I got back other exceptions in the Output. (System.TypeLoadException' occurred in itextsharp.DLL
System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
System.TypeLoadException' occurred in itextsharp.DLL
iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException' occurred in itextsharp.DLL
iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException' occurred in itextsharp.DLL)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pdf = await pdfFolder.GetFileAsync(Object.Path);
```

In this line of code you should only pass the file name but you are giving the whole Path as parameter. As pdfFolder currently represents the path.

Comment: This is confusing naming convention from me, but it cointais only the filename.For example "example.pdf". The function is throwing an exception when I pass the the path to the PdfReader.

Comment: have you tried **pdfToOpen.path** in place of Object.Path

Comment: No, but the it not an actual file. It is just the name of the specific object. 
But I will try.